# How to throw error in java reactive programming

Tags: java, microservices, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to throw error in service layer and excepting that error will be captured in controller layer in reactive way of implementation. But it is not happening now. The error occurring in controller is not  coming to controller catch block itself. Below are my code sample.

```
public class MyClass{
     
     public void getData(){
       try{
            Mono<String> result = myService.getResponseData(1);
       }catch(CustomException e){
        // I need to add diff logic when this type of exception occurs
       }catch(Exception e){
       // Here I need to add diff logic when this type of exception occurs
       }
     }
}

public classs MyService{
    public Mono<String>  getResponseData(int number){
        try{
            myDbDTO1.table1(number).map(
                    result -> {
                        if (validatingSomeCondition) {
                            throw new CustomException("Invalid data!");
                        }
                        return result;
                    })
                .zipWhen(result -> myDbDTO2
                        .table2(number).collectList())
                .map(m1 -> mapResults(m1.getT1(), m1.getT2()))
        }catch(CustomException){
            throw new CustomException("Invalid data!");
        }
    }
}

public Result mapResults(Result1 res1, Result2 res1){

    try{
        // I am combining both object and returing result
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new CustomException("Invalid data!");
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest any issue / anything i missed.

Thanks :)

Comment: So if your exception is not caught, what happens to it? Do you see a stack trace in the output?

Comment: Your custom exception should get emitted as an error event in your observable stream. It's not catchable in the traditional way. Instead it will show up inside your subscribe call as an error.

Comment: It is just logging and I saw stack trace aswell

Comment: check [Error Handling Operators](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_error_handling_operators) in the Reactor Reference Guide